# Accord avec personnes

Tags: expressions, accord

L'autre jour j'ai dit à un collègue :

> Personnes comme toi peuvent rentrer chez-elles pendant le week-end prolongé.

Du point de vue de la grammaire la tournure me paraît correcte. M'adressant à un homme pourtant, je ne sais pas si ma tournure est un peu gauche.

Comment: De mon point de vue, il manque quelque chose en début de phrase. Autant "Personne... ne" n'a pas besoin d'article, autant là il en faut un.

Comment: @XouDo Ma question porte sur l'accord. Mais tu penses que l'article défini manque en début (Les personnes...) ?

Comment: En français, il faut dire "des personnes comme toi". Alors, je suppose qui tu n'est pas grecque.....? οι άνδρες, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Personne" est un mot féminin donc "chez elles" est correct. La seule chose qui manque dans cette phrase est l'article pour ce mot:

> Les personnes comme toi peuvent rentrer chez elles pendant le week-end
> prolongé.

Peut-être as-tu voulu traduire "People" par "Personnes", en français, contrairement à en anglais, personne est 'pluralisable'. Il est fréquent d'entendre des francophones utiliser 'persons' pour traduire 'people', alors que dans la plupart des cas '1 person / >1 people'.

Comment: Merci. Mais pourquoi l'article défini est nécessaire ici ?

Comment: @Dimitris Par ce que l'on parle de personnes en particulier, celles qui sont dans la même situation que toi.

Comment: Nickel. J'ai compris. Donc l'accord avec personnes est bien fait (chez-elles). Mais, m'adressant à un homme, je trouve la tournure un peu gauche quand même. (Je ne suis pas locuteur natif.)

Comment: C'est pourtant correct. On dirait par contre: "Les employés comme toi peuvent rentrer chez eux pendant le week-end prolongé.".